# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am getting error when trying to use the dataframe.

This is piece of the code that Im running in databricks notebook in pyspark to get the data from snowflake

```
query = "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE LIMIT 10"
  SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
  df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query", query).load()
  print(type(df))
  print(df.count())
  print((df.count(), len(df.columns)))
```

Size of the dataframe and column count is correct.

when I do

```
df.show()
```

I am getting below error

```
  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1263.showString.
    : net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL access control error:
    Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:152)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:77)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:495)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:372)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:575)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:265)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:203)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:874)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeQueryInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:259)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.executeQuery(SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.java:181)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executePreparedQueryInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:317)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executePreparedQueryInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:315)
        at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:355)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me.

**EDIT:** Issue was because I was not authorised to create the temporary stage when running the query in the snowflake through spark.

Issue was resolved when I changed the snowflake client options like below:

```
sfOptions = {
        "sfURL": "xxx.snowflakecomputing.com",
        "sfUser": "xxxx",
        "sfDatabase": "TEMP", <- changed this to TEMP from PUBLIC
        "sfSchema": "PUBLIC",
        "sfWarehouse": "xxx",
        "sfRole": "xxxx",
        "pem_private_key": private_key
    }
```

They authorised devs to create temporary stage in the TEMP DB only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe executing the follow statements to grant access privileges is helping you. Reason could be that you granted select privileges to the table object but missed to grant usage privileges on database and/or schema level.

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE [database] TO ROLE [role];
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA [database].PUBLIC TO ROLE [role];
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE [database].PUBLIC.[table] TO ROLE [role];
```

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html

Comment: As I mentioned, I am able to run the queries in Snowflake dashboard.

Comment: You didnt mention or at least I cannot find that piece of information above.

Comment: If this is the case, you could take a look whether you are 100% using the same role in both scenarios.